# Smooch API for Twitter - ConsumerKey Mismatch errors

Tags: smooch

**Background**

I have set up a Twitter app & sandbox dev environment, from which I have a dev environment label ('*prod*'), consumer API key ('*abcdefghijk*') and an API secret key.

Using OAUTH I then obtained an access token & secret for the Twitter account I want to access using Twitter's Account Activity API.

Finally, using the Smooch API in node.js I have added the Twitter integration to one of my Smooch apps as follows:

```
smooch.integrations.create({
  appId: SMOOCH_APP_ID,
  props: {
    type: 'twitter',
    tier: 'sandbox',
    envName: 'prod',
    consumerKey: 'abcdefghijk',
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    accessTokenKey: TWITTER_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    accessTokenSecret: TWITTER_USER_ACCESS_SECRET
  })
```

...which registered the integration successfully and shows up as a new subscription in my Twitter developer dashboard ✓

**Problem**

In the logs for the Smooch app I see an entry status '*refused*', Error: '*Twitter ConsumerKey Mismatch: DrkY...[redacted]...DqOt*'

I do not recognise this ConsumerKey as being the one I used when setting up the new integration ('abcdefghijk'). I have verified that this is still the key registered on the application by running *smooch.integrations.list(SMOOCH_APP_ID)*, so.. **where is this other ConsumerKey coming from?**

Comment: Does the message still go through, and you get the mismatch error as well, or does the mismatch error prevent you from receiving messages?

Comment: We have a webhook integration set up and nothing is hitting it when these message events occur (so it is preventing messages being received).

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted state somewhere, have you tried removing and re-adding the integration?

Comment: I'll have someone from the Smooch customer success team follow up by email to debug this issue further

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @michaels - it's working now.

For anyone else who comes across this question, we migrated our Twitter API app to another Twitter account which seems to have caused this issue. This was a Twitter issue rather than a Smooch issue and was resolved by removing all subscriptions to the old app in Twitter.